# Is there a way to pack UVs to a selected area or avoid overlapping pinned UVs

Tags: uv, selection-tools

I am trying to fix this game asset's UVs. I have pinned UV islands which I do not want to move. But the rest of the UVs I want to unpack (again) into the same UV area without overlapping them. If I could get a similar texel density that would be a plus. If there is a plugin that would allow me to draw a square of where to pack UV islands/ where not to pack that would be ideal. I have the  UV-packer plugin but that does not seem to be able to do it. I am using Blender 3.6 or 4.0

[image]

When I try to pack islands with the pinned UVs locked it still overlaps:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

New Blender has an option to preserve the position of the islands when packing with pinning them with `UV` > `Pin`. Also the UV-Packer respects the pinned islands.

[image]

If it is just for a square to pack the new geometry into or the problem is with the UDIMs you can separate it into a new mesh pack it on its own and then joint the meshes. UDIMs are XY offsets by 1 for groups of UVs.

Can work them one by one using packing to the active UDIM.

[image]

Or use pack to `Original bound box`. But I guess you have to eyeball it.

[image]

I believe for free there is no option to pack islands to existing island across all UDIMs maximizing the area automatically. But looks like UVPackmaster can do that.

Comment: New Blender as in 4.0?

Comment: I have it on 4.0 Beta. https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/

Comment: I tried "pack islands" with "lock pinned islands" checked and it did not move my pinned islands but it still overlapped them

Comment: Are the pinned islands also selected?

Comment: Yes. I pinned the islands, then, I unwrapped the non-pinned UVs from my original post (to fix their UVs). Then I selected everything and did the pack islands command (with pinned locked).

Comment: With all the islands selected and options like in the first screenshot? Show the result.

Comment: I updated the post with the result

Comment: Either the new packer fails with unusual geometry like very small or distorted or you are not selecting all the islands both the pinned and the ones you are packing next to the pinned. Can you share the model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150349/discussion-between-ben-r-and-unwave).